# List index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, lista

Estoy escribiendo un codigo en python que una elementos de una lista de forma alternativa. Por ejemplo:  [a,b,c], [1,2,3] → [a,1,b,2,c,3]. Pero me da error "List index out of range". Este es mi codigo:

```
def unir_listas_alterno(lista1,lista2):
    nuevaLista = []
    contadorIndice = len(lista1) + len(lista2)
    contador = 0
    while(contador <contadorIndice):
        nuevaLista.append(lista1[contador]) #AQUI DA ERROR  
        nuevaLista.append(lista2[contador])                          
        contador+=1
    return nuevaLista

lista1 = ["a","b","c"]
lista2 = [1,2,3]
print(unir_listas_alterno(lista1,lista2)) #AQUI DA ERROR
```

Comment: porque `contador` llega a ser mayor que la longitud de la lista. El `contadorIndice` no deberia ser la suma, si no solo la longitud de la lista más corta. Si siempre van a tener la misma longitud no pasa nada, pero si una es más corta que la otra tendrás que parar  cuando llegues a la longitud de la corta y luego añadir lo restante de la más larga. (aqui tienes [una pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347065/interweaving-two-numpy-arrays) donde se explica usando numpy)

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta tiene que ver mucho a sí se asume que las listas tienen igual cantidad de valores o no.

**En caso que tengan la misma cantidad de elementos**, la respuesta te la ha dado lois6b el problema lo tienes en esta sentencia: `contadorIndice = len(lista1) + len(lista2)`. `contadorIndice` es la variable que usarás para iterar "hasta", el problema es que en tu ejemplo el valor `contadorIndice` será 6, entonces cuando la iteración logre llegar al 4 aparecerá el error, simplemente por que las listas tienen 3 elementos únicamente (`lista1[contador]`). La solución es sencilla, solo iterar hasta la longitud de alguna de las listas, no importa cuál, en este caso son iguales, por ejemplo: **`while(contador <len(lista1))`**

**En cambio si las listas no tienen la misma lóngitud**, el problema es otro un poco más complejo. Por empezar habría que definir que se debe hacer en estos casos, si la idea es que quedarse con una lista del que combine solo un elemento de una y otro de otra, la iteración deberías hacerla hasta `contadorIndice = min(len(lista1),len(lista2))` es decir hasta la longitud de la lista más chica. Si por el contrario se busca que la lista final sea la suma de ambas listas, hay que hacer algunas modificaciones adicionales y aquí sí deberíamos iterar hasta el `contadorIndice = max(len(lista1),len(lista2))`. Como ejemplo de esto último, este sería el código:

```
def unir_listas_alterno(lista1,lista2):
    nuevaLista = []
    contadorIndice = max(len(lista1),len(lista2))
    contador = 0
    while(contador < contadorIndice):
        if len(lista1) > contador:
            nuevaLista.append(lista1[contador])
        if len(lista2) > contador:
            nuevaLista.append(lista2[contador])
        contador+=1
    return nuevaLista

lista1 = ["a","b","c"]
lista2 = [1,2,3,4]
print(unir_listas_alterno(lista1,lista2))
```

Por supuesto hay formas mucho más compactas de resolver estas situaciones, por ejemplo el uso de [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) que básicamente irá combinando elemento a elemento armando tuplas del tipo `("a", 1), (b, "2"), ("c", 3), (None, 4)` que luego simplemente hay que "aplanar" para convertir todo en una lista.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

lista1 = ["a","b","c"]
lista2 = [1,2,3, 4]

lista_final = [e for l in list(izip_longest(lista1, lista2)) for e in l if e]
print(lista_final)

> ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Como muy bién te indica lois6b en su comentario `contadorIndice` debe ser igual a la longitud de las listas (ambas deben tener la misma longitud), en tu ejemplo debe ser 3, luego esa línea debe ser:

```
contadorIndice = len(lista1)
```

Con eso tu código es correcto siempre y cuando te asegures de pasar dos listas con el mismo número de elementos.

Hay mucha otras opciones más eficintes y simples por si interesan:

- Usar `range` junto a un `for`:

  ```
  def unir_listas_alterno(lista1,lista2):
      nuevaLista = []
      for i in range(len(lista1)):
          nuevaLista.append(lista1[i])
          nuevaLista.append(lista2[i])
      return nuevaLista
  ```
- Usando un `for` con `enumerate`:

  ```
  def unir_listas_alterno(lista1,lista2):
      nuevaLista = []
      for i,  e1 in enumerate(lista1):
          nuevaLista.append(e1)
          nuevaLista.append(lista2[i])
      return nuevaLista
  ```
- Usando `zip` junto a `list.extend`:

  ```
  def unir_listas_alterno(lista1,lista2):
      nuevaLista = []
      for pair in zip(lista1, lista2):
          nuevaLista.extend(pair)
      return nuevaLista
  ```
- Compresión de listas con `zip`:

  ```
  def unir_listas_alterno(lista1,lista2):
      return [elemento for pareja in zip(lista1, lista2) for elemento in pareja]
  ```
- Mi opción preferida es usar la `chain.from_iterable` de la biblioteca `itertools`:

  ```
  import itertools

  def unir_listas_alterno(lista1, lista2):
      return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(lista1, lista2)))
  ```

Deberías considerar validar la entrada, asegurándote que ambas listas tienen la misma longitud y lanzando una excepción en caso contrario. Simplemente puedes hacer al inicio de la función algo como:

```
def unir_listas_alterno(lista1, lista2):
    if len(lista1) != len(lista2):
        raise ValueError("Ambas listas han de tener el mismo número de elementos")
```

Algunas medidas de tiempos de ejecución (1000000 llamadas a la función con listas de 300 elementos):

> **while:**
>   1000000 loops, best of 3: 55.43 sec per loop
>   **for + range:**
>   1000000 loops, best of 3: 47.46 sec per loop
>   **for + enumerate:**
>   1000000 loops, best of 3: 41.98 sec per loop
>   **zip + extend:**
>   1000000 loops, best of 3: 23.40 sec per loop
>   **zip en compresión de listas:**
>   1000000 loops, best of 3: 24.28 sec per loop
>   **chain.from_iterable + zip:**
>   1000000 loops, best of 3: 14.16 sec per loop

Se observa como `itertools.chain.from_iterable` es considerablemente más eficiente con respecto al resto de opciones.