# Error: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto y es mi primer programa con python, pero no se que esta mal exactamente, ayuda.

```
while i <= 80:
    prueba = [int(i)]
    i += 5
    m += 1

print("Resultados")

while c <= m:
    print("Prueba" + str(c))
    print("Presion:" + str(prueba[c]))
    c += 1
```

Me sale este error:

```
    print("Presion:" + str(prueba[c]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: ¿Estas adjuntando todo el código? según veo en el código hay variables que no has definido o declarado, y parece ser que no te da error, esos fallos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estaría bueno que expliques mejor lo que deseas hacer para tener mas idea de como darte una solución mas especifica y sea mas fácil realizar una mejor explicación.
De todas maneras corregí tu código para que puedas verlo y sacar tus conclusiones. Saludos!

```
#inicializo las variables!
i=0
m=0
prueba=[]
while i <= 80:
    prueba.append(i) #el metodo append permite agregar elementos al final de la list
    i += 5
    m += 1

print("Resultados")
c=0
while c < m:
    print("Prueba ", c)
    print("Presion:", prueba[c])
    print("\n")
    c+=1
```

También te dejo una pregunta de otro usuario con el mismo problema que tiene muy buenas respuestas!

[List index out of range](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/117044/list-index-out-of-range?rq=1)